# Amazon SnS push notifications are not sent

Tags: java, android, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I am trying to send push notifications through amazon sns.
When i manually created GCm application at amazon and application endpoint it gives following error

```
{Message Body: {"GCM":"{\"collapse_key\":\"Welcome\",\"data\":{\"message\":\"Hello World!\"},\"delay_while_idle\":true,\"time_to_live\":125,\"dry_run\":false}"}}
{Message Attributes:}
May 12, 2015 11:10:09 AM com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient logRequestId
INFO: x-amzn-RequestId: 60749365-b72d-5a0e-8eca-deae2ca89839
Caught an AmazonServiceException, which means your request made it to Amazon SNS, but was rejected with an error response for some reason.
Error Message:    Invalid parameter: TargetArn Reason: No endpoint found for the target arn specified (Service: AmazonSNS; Status Code: 400; Error Code: InvalidParameter; Request ID: 60749365-b72d-5a0e-8eca-deae2ca89839)
HTTP Status Code: 400
AWS Error Code:   InvalidParameter
Error Type:       Client
Request ID:       60749365-b72d-5a0e-8eca-deae2ca89839
```

but when i create application and endpoint arns in java  it says

```
{EndpointArn:` arn:aws:sns:us-west-1:891575093309:endpoint/GCM/TestApp/3a1b5884-1533-3997-a819-9f362c3126f7}
{Message Body: {"GCM":"{\"collapse_key\":\"Welcome\",\"data\":{\"message\":\"Hello World!\"},\"delay_while_idle\":true,\"time_to_live\":125,\"dry_run\":false}"}}
{Message Attributes:}
Published! 
{MessageId=e5f9452e-09c7-5a94-9cf1-08e597674c00}
```

but i didnot receive any notifications. Please any one who has luckily implemented it...

Comment: It may well be that the event is not getting to sns correctly as you say, but its worth ruling out that it is your subscription that is not working first. How are you subscribing to the topic? Have you tried manually sending a message through the web console to confirm that the subscription is working properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was with GCM enabled google app i created new and used its server api key all worked fine...